# Meaning of $x^m + y^n = z^r$ (mod $p_1$)

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand how to find a counter example to the Beal Conjecture. One site ([here](http://www.danvk.org/wp/beals-conjecture/)) says that,

> According to The Prime Pages, the largest primes less than $2^{32}$ are $p_1 = 2^{32}-5$ and $p_2 = 2^{32}-17$. If $x^m + y^n = z^r$ (mod $p_1$) and $x^m + y^n = z^r$ (mod $p_2$).

What does modulus $p_1$ and $p_2$ mean? What is p? And what would the modulus be take of? Would it be $x^m + y^n$? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ are already defined in your question (although it is stated incorrectly here because you didn't include carrots ^ and the editor didn't realize they were supposed to be powers). While the string of words "what would the modulus be take of" is close to gibberish, please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic and you might understand better.

Comment: @anon I understand that first part now, but I just don't get what would be the equation. For example, would it be `x^m % p1` with % being mod?

Comment: @anon You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmers think about `mod` as a binary operation, where you have inputs `a` and `n` and the output is `Mod(a,n)`, which is the remainder of `a` upon division by `n`.

This is *not* how mathematicians think about modular arithmetic. (The programmer's `mod` operation is just called the "division algorithm" in number theory.)

We think about 'mod' as something called a *congruence relation*. Numbers $a$ and $b$ are "congruent modulo $n$" if $a$ and $b$ differ by a multiple of $n$. For example, "$5\equiv11$ mod $3$" because the difference between $5$ and $11$ is $6$ which is divisible by $3$.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic for more detailed information.

Comment: So it seems like it would be ($x^m +y^n - z^r)/ p_1 = remainder$ $0$, however, how can this work since the sum shouldn't be close to $p_1$? (Also, $x^m +y^n$ should equal $z^r$, so some results from this should have $x^m +y^n =z^r$.)

Comment: Do you suggest making another post with this question?

Comment: @hichris123 Your call. One, "$/p_1=remainder0$" is technically meaningless, although it's clear you mean that the division by $p_1$ yields remainder $0$. Second, in what sense and why is the sum (what is "the sum"?) close to $p_1$, and why would that be relevant or an issue, and what does "results from this should have $=$" mean? Do you have a first language other than English?

Comment: I am a native English speaker. :P I'm probably not explaining it very well, as I'm not too clear about this. The [site I linked](http://www.danvk.org/wp/beals-conjecture/) may be able to explain it better. Basically, the result set of this should have a subset of it in which $x^m + y^n = z^r$. However, not all of the result has to have that.

Comment: @hichris123 For given $m,n,r$ if there is a solution $(x,y,z)$ to the equation $x^m+y^n=z^r$ then $(x,y,z)$ will be among the solutions to $x^m+y^n\equiv z^r\bmod p$. However, conversely, even when there are solutions to a congruence like $A\equiv B\bmod p$ there may not be a corresponding solution to the equation $A=B$. Does that have anything to do with what you're trying to ask?

Comment: That basically is the essence of what I'm trying to ask. I believe to find a solution of $x^m + y^n ≡ mod$ $p$, you would do $(x^m + y^n - z^r)/ p$ and find those that have a remainder of zero when doing that division. Am I correct on thinking that?

Comment: @hichris123 $A\equiv B\bmod p$ is the same as $A-B$ having remainder $0$ upon division by $p$. If someone gave you specific numbers and asked if they were a solution to the congruence, then in order to check that you would plug the numbers into $x^m+y^n-z^r$ and see if the result is cleanly divisible by $p$. If you want to characterize the whole solution set, that will require serious theoretical tools, and writing out the definition of $A\equiv B\bmod p$ wouldn't really be a step toward a solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I'm not trying to characterize the solution set, just wanted to understand this. Figuring out what $x^m + y^n ≡ z^r mod$ $p$ meant and how it could be written out was my goal. Thanks!